# Changing the order of XML when rendering with XSL

Tags: html, xml, xslt, web

I'm having an issue where I want to render a list of cars in the browser in a particular order but the XML is in a different order (which cannot be changed).

How can I write my XSL to render cars of the same make together, ordered by their top speed?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Vehicle>
    <Car>
        <Make>Audi</Make>
        <Model>R8</Model>
        <TopSpeed>200</TopSpeed>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <Make>Lamborghini</Make>
        <Model>Aventador</Model>
        <TopSpeed>250</TopSpeed>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <Make>Ferrari</Make>
        <Model>TDF</Model>
        <TopSpeed>220</TopSpeed>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <Make>Lamborghini</Make>
        <Model>Gallardo</Model>
        <TopSpeed>200</TopSpeed>
    </Car>
</Vehicle>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
<body>
  <h2>My Car Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th style="text-align:left">Make</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Model</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Top Speed</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="Vehicle/Car">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Make"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Model"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="TopSpeed"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This outputs a table in the following order:

- Audi R8
- Lamborghini Aventador
- Ferrari TDF
- Lamborghini Gallardo

But I'm trying to get the two Lamborghinis to appear one after the order, highest top speed first.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So you want to group by `Make`, see http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml for the text book approach to grouping in XSLT 1.0. Then sort the items in each group by the speed.

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen I'll give that a go and post up a solution if it helps

Comment: If you do not need to span the row of the table, you can just add:        <xsl:sort select="Make"/> and <xsl:sort select="TopSpeed"/> after the xsl:for-each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comments suggest, consider running the Muenchian Grouping with a `<xsl:sort>`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="makeid" match="Car" use="Make" />

  <xsl:template match="Vehicle">
    <html>
    <body>
      <h2>My Car Collection</h2>
      <table border="1">
       <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
         <th style="text-align:left">Make</th>
         <th style="text-align:left">Model</th>
         <th style="text-align:left">Top Speed</th>
       </tr>              
       <xsl:apply-templates select="Car[generate-id() = generate-id(key('makeid', Make)[1])]"/>        
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Car[generate-id() = generate-id(key('makeid', Make)[1])]">        
        <xsl:for-each select="key('makeid',Make)">    
          <xsl:sort select="TopSpeed" order="descending" data-type="number"/>      
          <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Make"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Model"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="TopSpeed"/></td>
          </tr>              
        </xsl:for-each>              
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>My Car Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">Make</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Model</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Top Speed</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Audi</td>
        <td>R8</td>
        <td>200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lamborghini</td>
        <td>Aventador</td>
        <td>250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lamborghini</td>
        <td>Gallardo</td>
        <td>200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ferrari</td>
        <td>TDF</td>
        <td>220</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: HTML Output]

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example of Muenchian grouping, but done slightly different. It also sorts by Make before sorting by Top Speed.

**XML Input** (modified to be a little more out of order)

```
<Vehicle>
    <Car>
        <Make>Lamborghini</Make>
        <Model>Gallardo</Model>
        <TopSpeed>200</TopSpeed>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <Make>Audi</Make>
        <Model>R8</Model>
        <TopSpeed>200</TopSpeed>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <Make>Lamborghini</Make>
        <Model>Aventador</Model>
        <TopSpeed>250</TopSpeed>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <Make>Ferrari</Make>
        <Model>TDF</Model>
        <TopSpeed>220</TopSpeed>
    </Car>
</Vehicle>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="carsByMake" match="Car" use="Make"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <html> 
      <body>
        <h2>My Car Collection</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th style="text-align:left">Make</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Model</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Top Speed</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="Car[count(.|key('carsByMake',Make)[1])=1]">
            <xsl:sort select="Make"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('carsByMake',Make)">
              <xsl:sort select="TopSpeed" order="descending"/>
              <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="Make"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="Model"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="TopSpeed"/></td>
              </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>My Car Collection</h2>
      <table border="1">
         <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th style="text-align:left">Make</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Model</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Top Speed</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Audi</td>
            <td>R8</td>
            <td>200</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Ferrari</td>
            <td>TDF</td>
            <td>220</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Lamborghini</td>
            <td>Aventador</td>
            <td>250</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Lamborghini</td>
            <td>Gallardo</td>
            <td>200</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```